# How to troubleshoot WordPress issues?

Tags: troubleshooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you debug plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-do-you-debug-plugins)

I have an issue that the posts table shows "no posts found" right after the installation although I can see "All (1) | Published (1)" right above it.

Now I'm not asking how to fix this very issue, I'd rather **learn how to troubleshoot such issues in general**. Is there a log file? (Haven't found one.) Is there some plugin that would help with seeing which SQL commands are executed and what data is returned? Something to display PHP warnings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

1. Use the Debug Bar plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/
2. Set WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php file if you are looking for problems in a theme or plugin
3. I created a plugin that allows you to dump any variable into the Debug Bar plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kint-debugger/ You should look at the global $wp_query var to see the query that is being executed.

Beyond that, there are dozens of debug plugins on the plugin repo.