# Getting a WordPress Debug Strategy

Tags: plugin-development, php, theme-development, debug, wp-debug

I have been reading up on debugging. I watched Chip Bennett's [video](http://wordpress.tv/2011/11/06/chip-bennett-wordpress-theme-repository-developingsubmitting/) on wordpress.tv and was inspired to take debugging seriously. What I have found in my reading up though has confused me a bit. I know about `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and some of the debug plugins like 'debug bar' and 'firephp' and also 'log deprecated functions', and having read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-do-you-debug-plugins) I fine plenty more ways to debug WordPress, but I can't conceive an overall strategy.

What I mean is: is it ok to just use just `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` ... and if so then what are the plugins for. I think I understand the difference between these and say 'log deprecated functions' for instance but I am slightly blinded by the light I think with regard to the others. I know I could just install each plugin and play with it till I can answer this question but I really had hoped that someone could save me the time with a little direction.

Mainly what I want to know is this: am I right in thinking that `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` is where it starts and the plugins are just improving on that, so that if I get ONE good plugin that works for me then I dont necessarily need to do anything else (like using a combination of these plugins) ... OR is it probably necessary to use a combination of debugging plugins and aids and if so what are people's recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several tools at your disposal when working with native WordPress debugging.

**PHP Debugging** - `WP_DEBUG` is the native WordPress PHP constant for debugging WordPress errors. It sets PHP's error reporting to to `E_ALL` for warnings when deprecated functions are used and if none are found it sets it to `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_USER_NOTICE`.

So most of the time setting `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` is enough.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

**Database Query**
To debug database queries you need to set `define('SAVEQUERIES', true);`
This is a very handy tool that will benchmark and perform some analysis in your `$wpdb` query.

**Javascript**
To debug any javascript you can turn on `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);`

That is pretty much it in terms of WordPress itself, plugins like the [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) simply make it easy to read the results, since debugging output can be quite messy. For example look at the `SAVEQUERIES` in the debug bar, it is very easy to read.

There are other plugins that extend the capabilities of debugging because they provide more information and better output, I made a list of some here since this question comes up quite often, http://debugggg.wordpress.com/